# How does React-Router-4 check for additional (unnecessary) slashes "/" typed in manually?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

There's a potential bug I found in react router. In my component, I do this:

```
if(this.props.location.pathname === "/home")
```

to check whether the user is at a path. It can be buggy, because the above condition is `false` if the user enters the URL manually, like example.com/home/

How to handle this case? It's ugly to do multiple checking like this:

```
if(this.props.location.pathname === "/home" || this.props.location.pathname === "/home/"))
```

Any suggestions on how I could do this in a better and cleaner way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

`if (this.props.location.pathname.match(/^\/home\/?$/g))`

That will exactly match either `/home` or `/home/`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to achieve you can mix `exact` and `strict` attributes. I suggest looking into this ;)

### **strict: bool**

Match from strictly; equivalent to `Route.strict`.

```
// this will match both /home and /home/

<Route exact path="/foo" strict={false} component={foo} />
```

For future references here's a [link](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Route/strict-bool) to official docs.

Comment: default the strict is `undefined` right? why do I need to use strict in my case?

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be used accepted instead of the currently accepted answer of pattern matching. It's literally what you want @AlisaTMorgan.

Comment: @AlisaTMorgan -Well, your "case" is kinda strange, and in 99,99% cases that type of behavior/ solution is not required. Since you asked, I offered help and show you that nice people @ React-Router team are doing a great job, so there's a nice solution for your case too. Usually if a user types in (manually) an additional slash "/" it gets removed automatically by the browser. `undefined` means just that -it's not present, but if you do it as I showed you, the job gets done correctly and easily. I suggest visiting the link I provider for further references. Have a nice day.
@nbokmans Thank you

Comment: user go to example.com/dashboard, and the user can also go to example.com/dashboard/

Comment: No, I understand you, completely. I'm just saying adding this `strict={false}` is clean, easy, and should solve the problem for you. Happy hacking :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using:

```
this.props.match.path
```

Comment: what is the different using this.props.location vs this.props.match?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `indexOf`:

`if (this.props.location.indexOf("home") >= 1)`

```js
const URL = ["home", "/home", "/home/", "/home/about", "/about", "/logout", "/login/home"];

URL.forEach(url => {
 const isMatch = url.indexOf("home") >= 1 
 console.log(`${url} is a match? ${isMatch}`);
})
```

The caveat (or benefit) is that it can match to any URL combination with `/home` in it (as shown above).

Comment: this is the same as using includes right? I want exact match, not partial exist